# Inline editor for complex property in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this simple model:

```
public class ContactPersonDto 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ContactName { get; set; }
   public PhoneDto ContactPhone { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneDto 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to create a grid for ContactPersonDto with inline editing. Currently my code is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ContactPersonDto>()
            .Name("GridContactPersons")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(x => x.ContactName);
                columns.Bound(x => x.ContactPhone).ClientTemplate("#= phoneTemplate(ContactPhone) #");
                columns.Command(command =>
                {
                    command.Edit();
                    command.Destroy();
                }).Width(200);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("CustomerContactPersons_Read", "Customer"))
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(x => x.Id);
                    model.Field(x => x.ContactPhone);
                    model.Field(x => x.ContactPhone.Id);
                    model.Field(x => x.ContactPhone.Number);
                })
            .Create("CreateCustomerContactPerson", "Customer")
            .Update("UpdateCustomerContactPerson", "Customer")
            .Destroy("DeleteCustomerContactPerson", "Customer")
            )
        )
```

where phoneTemplate(ContactPhone) is simple js function which take a phone Number and group digits. 
I have this template for PhoneDto:

```
@model PhoneDto

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)

<div class="k-edit-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Number)</div>
<div class="k-edit-field">
    @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(x => x).Mask("(000) 000-0000").UnmaskOnPost(true)
</div>
```

Here is my grid:
[image: Grid]

And it works well except adding a new item. 
I receive: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactPhone is not defined` when I press 'Add new record' button. I found that problem occurs only for complex properties, for e.g string ContactName everything goes smoothly. 
Please, help me with this. 
Is there a way to use complex properties in kendo grid?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding default value for ContactPhone:

```
.DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("CustomerContactPersons_Read", "Customer"))
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(x => x.Id);
                    model.Field(x => x.ContactPhone).DefaultValue(new PhoneDto { Type = PhoneType.Default });
                })
```